How long have your audiomoths lasted (total lifespan)?
I'm deploying audiomoths for a contract (weatherproof cases, 3 months of continuous deployment per year). I need to factor in a reasonable cost to cover moth replacement but I'm not sure how long I can expect them to keep working. Can anyone please share their experiences regarding failure rates, rates of replacement for parts and ideal deployment lifespan of our little green friends.

can you be a little more clearer on what you mean by replacement? whole moth, batteries, uSD card, Settings (duty cycling, frequency)?

I'd be happy for any information whatsoever regarding failure rates (moths, cases, noise filters, uSD). For additional context: I deploy for 12-14 weeks at a time, once a year in austral spring/summer. This includes infrequent low volume rainfall events and high daily temperatures. I record two 5-minute recordings each day of deployment at 48 kHz with medium gain (my Nyquist rate is about 16). During the last deployment I lost 10-20% of my audio filters (due to birds or insects). Some filters were destroyed entirely, others just had a pinhole and need replacing.

About 8% of the units had incursion of water following damage to the filter. I lost recordings but all units still appeared to be working when tested. These deployments only require 1 set of batteries.

I deployed 55 audiomoths for roughly 3 months total in the tropics, both dry and wet seasons, and lost 3 to battery corrosion, 1 to a broken switch. Wet season means daily serious downpours. I also had 14 of the waterproof acoustic vent stickers on the weatherproof cases get ripped (mostly by ants), so those needed replacing. One of the case latch mechanisms broke.
